# Excel (2007) hyperlink not opening MP3 file in Win Media Player

Tags: excel, mp3, excel-2007

O/S - WIN 10 (initial version without update)
MS Office 2007

I have a list of my MP3 songs in Excel with hyperlink to each file in the folder. When I click on the cell Media Player automatically opened and played the file. About a week ago, for no apparent reason, this stopped. Instead, when I click on the name, a message pops up saying

`"This operation has been canceled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator."`

Only I use the laptop with admin permission. But I do not know what to do. Please help me to find a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by saving as "Single file web page", the hyperlink is working and the songs open automatically in media player.